# PHP Ajax - Show part of the data in a table?

Tags: php, ajax

There are texareas in my table: "Case Description", "Case Notes", etc..

I want the case description not to show the entire textarea of more than 500 characters in the `<td>`...

I want it more like:

```
This is a case description....
```

When the Edit button is clicked, it pops a modal to edit the data via ajax (already done).

Here are my codes

Edit-report.php:

```
<!-- Start PHP While -->
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'mushref', 'Almadina1!', 'security_db')
or die('Dramatic Error: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli));

if( isset($_POST['id']) ) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $ccc_employee = $_POST['cccEmployee'];
    $IR_number = $_POST['irNumber'];
    $case_type = $_POST['caseType'];
    $caseLocation = $_POST['caseLocation'];
    $startDate = $_POST['startDateTime'];
    $endDate = $_POST['endDateTime'];
    $case_description = $_POST['caseDesc'];
    $action_taken = $_POST['actionsTaken'];
    $details = $_POST['caseDetails'];
    $notes = $_POST['caseNotes'];
    $recommendation = $_POST['caseRecommendation'];

    // Query to update data
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE cases_reports SET
    cccEmployee='$ccc_employee',
    irNumber='$IR_number',
    caseType='$case_type',
    caseLocation='$caseLocation',
    startDateTime='$startDate',
    endDateTime='$endDate',
    caseDesc='$case_description',
    actionsTaken='$action_taken',
    caseDetails='$details',
    caseNotes='$notes',
    caseRecommendation='$recommendation'
    WHERE id='$id'");
}

$selectquery = "SELECT * FROM cases_reports";

$table = mysqli_query($mysqli, $selectquery);
$nums = mysqli_num_rows($table);

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($table)) {
?>

<tr id="<?php echo $res['id']?>">
<td data-target="cccEmployee"><?php echo $res['cccEmployee'];?></td>
<td data-target="IR_number"><?php echo $res['irNumber'];?></td>
<td data-target="case_type"><?php echo $res['caseType'];?></td>
<td data-target="case_location"><?php echo $res['caseLocation'];?></td>
<td data-target="startDateTime"><?php echo $res['startDateTime'];?></td>
<td data-target="endtDateTime"><?php echo $res['endDateTime'];?></td>
<td data-target="case_description"><?php echo $res['caseDesc'];?></td>
<td data-target="actions_taken"><?php echo $res['actionsTaken'];?></td>
<td data-target="case_details"><?php echo $res['caseDetails'];?></td>
<td data-target="case_notes"><?php echo $res['caseNotes'];?></td>
<td data-target="case_recommendation"><?php echo $res['caseRecommendation'];?></td>
<td class="table-actions">
    <a href="#" data-role="update" data-id="<?php echo $res['id']; ?>">
        <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
    </a>
    <!-- <a href="#!" class="table-action table-action-delete" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Delete product">
        <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
    </a> -->
</td>
<td>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-icon-only text-light" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-arrow">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Print PDF</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Export Excel</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Export Access</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
</tr>

<div class="modal fade" id="reportsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal- modal-dialog-centered modal-" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h6 class="modal-title" id="modal-title-default"> Case Details </h6>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
        </div>   
    <div class="modal-body" id="case-data">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="cccEmployee">CCC Employee</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cccEmployee" name="cccEmployee">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="IR_number">IR Number</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">IR#</span>
              </div>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="IR_number" name="IR_number">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-control-label" for="case_type">Case Type</label>
            <select data-toggle="select" class="form-control" name="case_type" id="case_type">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select Case Type</option>
                <option value="Accident">Accident</option>
                <option value="Theft">Theft</option>
                <option value="Death">Death</option>
                <option value="Harrasment">Harrasment</option>
                <option value="badBehaviour">Bad Behaviour</option>
                <option value="Drugs">Drugs</option>
                <option value="Drunk">Drunk</option>
                <option value="Fight">Fight</option>
                <option value="Medical">Medical</option>
                <option value="illegalEntry">Illegal Entry</option>
                <option value="illegalWorker">Illegal Worker</option>
                <option value="Fire">Fire</option>
                <option value="Electric">Electric</option>
                <option value="illegalHunting">Illegal Hunting</option>
                <option value="oilLeak">Oil Leak</option>
                <option value="petrolLeak">Petrol Leak</option>
                <option value="Kidnapping">Kidnapping</option>
                <option value="Blackmail">Blackmail</option>
                <option value="Misunderstanding">Misunderstanding</option>
                <option value="propertyDamage">Property Damage</option>
                <option value="smoke_NoFire">Smoke, No Fire</option>
                <option value="stuck_InElevator">Stuck in Elevator</option>
                <option value="Scooter">Scooter</option>
                <option value="Drifting">Drifting</option>
                <option value="LostPerson">Lost Person</option>
                <option value="Fraud_Forgery">Fraud/Forgery</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="case_location">Location</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="case_location" id="case_location" data-toggle="select">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select Location</option>
                <option value="Baylasun">Baylasun</option>
                <option value="Baylasun Hotel">Baylasun Hotel</option>
                <option value="AL-Waha">AL-Waha</option>
                <option value="Al-Morooj">Al-Morooj</option>
                <option value="Royal Green">Royal Green</option>
                <option value="Beach Towers">Beach Towers</option>
                <option value="Emmar Building">Emmar Building</option>
                <option value="Industrial Area (East)">Industrial Area (East)</option>
                <option value="Industrial Area (West)">Industrial Area (West)</option>
                <option value="Hejaz Gate">Hejaz Gate</option>
                <option value="Gate 3">Gate 3</option>
                <option value="Marina 1">Marina 1</option>
                <option value="Marina 2">Marina 2</option>
                <option value="Marina 3">Marina 3</option>
                <option value="Tala Garden">Tala Garden</option>
                <option value="AL-Shorooq">AL-Shorooq</option>
                <option value="Yam Beach">Yam Beach</option>
                <option value="Sales Center">Sales Center</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="startDate">Start Date & Time</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="startDate" id="startDateTime">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-control-label" for="endDateTime">End Date & Time</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="endDateTime" id="endDateTime">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-control-label" for="case_description">Case Description</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="case_description" id="case_description" rows="3"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-control-label" for="actions_taken">Actions Taken</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="actions_taken" id="actions_taken"></textarea>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-control-label" for="details">Details</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="case_details" id="case_details"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="case_notes">Notes</label>
            <textarea name="case_notes" id="case_notes" class="form-control"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="case_recommendation">Recommendations</label>
            <textarea name="case_recommendation" id="case_recommendation" class="form-control"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="caseId" class="form-control"/> 
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" id="save_report_changes" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>    
</div>
<?php } //End php While ?>
```

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      // Append values in input fields
      $(document).on('click', 'a[data-role=update]', function(){
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            var cccEmployee = $("#"+id).children('td[data-target=cccEmployee]').text();
            var irNumber = $("#"+id).children('td[data-target=IR_number]').text();
            var caseType = $("#"+id).children('td[data-target=case_type]').text();
            var caseLocation = $("#"+id).children('td[data-target=case_location]').text();
            var startDateTime = $("#"+id).children('td[data-target=startDateTime]').text();
            var endDateTime = $("#"+id).children('td[data-target=endDateTime]').text();
            var caseDesc = $("#"+id).children('td[data-target=case_description]').text();
            var actionsTaken = $("#"+id).children('td[data-target=actions_taken]').text();
            var caseDetails = $("#"+id).children('td[data-target=case_details]').text();
            var caseNotes = $("#"+id).children('td[data-target=case_notes]').text();
            var caseRecommendation = $("#"+id).children('td[data-target=case_recommendation]').text();

         //Append the variables
         $('#cccEmployee').val(cccEmployee);
         $('#IR_number').val(irNumber);
         $('#case_type').val(caseType);
         $('#case_location').val(caseLocation);
         $('#startDateTime').val(startDateTime);
         $('#endDateTime').val(endDateTime);
         $('#case_description').val(caseDesc);
         $('#actions_taken').val(actionsTaken);
         $('#case_details').val(caseDetails);
         $('#case_notes').val(caseNotes);
         $('#case_recommendation').val(caseRecommendation);
         $('#caseId').val(id);

         $('#reportsModal').modal('toggle');
      });

      //Create event to get data from fields and update.
      $('#save_report_changes').click(function() {
         var id = $('#caseId').val();
         var cccEmployee = $('#cccEmployee').val();
         var irNumber =  $('#IR_number').val();
         var caseType = $('#case_type').val();
         var caseLocation = $('#case_location').val();
         var startDateTime = $('#startDateTime').val();
         var endDateTime = $('#endDateTime').val();
         var caseDesc = $('#case_description').val();
         var actionsTaken = $('#actions_taken').val();
         var caseDetails = $('#case_details').val();
         var caseNotes = $('#case_notes').val();
         var caseRecommendation = $('#case_recommendation').val();

         $.ajax({
            url: '/edit-report',
            method: 'post',
            data: {
               id: id,
               cccEmployee: cccEmployee,
               irNumber: irNumber,
               caseType: caseType,
               caseLocation: caseLocation,
               startDateTime: startDateTime,
               endDateTime: endDateTime,
               caseDesc: caseDesc,
               actionsTaken: actionsTaken,
               caseDetails: caseDetails,
               caseNotes: caseNotes,
               caseRecommendation: caseRecommendation
            },
            success: function(response) {
               
               $("#"+id).children('td[data-target=cccEmployee]').text(cccEmployee);
               $("#"+id).children('td[data-target=IR_number]').text(irNumber);
               $("#"+id).children('td[data-target=case_type]').text(caseType);
               $("#"+id).children('td[data-target=case_location]').text(caseLocation);
               $("#"+id).children('td[data-target=startDateTime]').text(startDateTime);
               $("#"+id).children('td[data-target=endDateTime]').text(endDateTime);
               $("#"+id).children('td[data-target=case_description]').text(caseDesc);
               $("#"+id).children('td[data-target=actions_taken]').text(actionsTaken);
               $("#"+id).children('td[data-target=case_details]').text(caseDetails);
               $("#"+id).children('td[data-target=case_notes]').text(caseNotes);
               $("#"+id).children('td[data-target=case_recommendation]').text(caseRecommendation);
               
               $('#reportsModal').modal('toggle');
            },
         });
      });
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mb_strimwidth("Hello World", 0, 10, "...");`
where "Hello Word is your description"
This will return This will return `Hello W....`